# Python code to list all the tables created and tables used to create it from sql script

Tags: sql, text-mining

```
Hi, just wanted to know if you can output such a way that, Created tables and tables used to create that tables can be grouped together

eg 
'select * from A inner join B on A.id=B.id
                 inner join C on A.id=C.id

 select * from D inner join E on D.id=E.id
                 inner join F on D.id=F.id' 

output should be:
1.tables created A---Input table B, C
2.tables created D---Input table E, F
```

output should be:

1.tables created A---Input table B, C

2.tables created D---Input table E, F